# Maven + TestNG Print parameters of @DataProvider

Tags: java, maven, testng, dataprovider

The question is simple but I can't find it anywhere (googling) I want to run `mvn test` and see in the console output the next text "`PASSED: theNameOfMyTest("A String Attribute")`" the code that will produce this example would look something like this:

```
import static org.testng.Assert.assertTrue;

public class TestClass {

    @DataProvider(name = "provider")
    public static Object[][] provider() {
        return new Object[][] {{"A String Attribute"}};
    }

    @Test(dataProvioder="provider")
    public void theNameOfMyTest(final String parameter) {
        assertTrue(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your own [Listener](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners) which will display the expected information. Then, configure surefire to use it: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html

```
public class MyTestListener extends TestListenerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void onTestFailure(ITestResult tr) {
    log("FAIL: ", tr);
  }

  @Override
  public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult tr) {
    log("SKIPPED: ", tr);
  }

  @Override
  public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult tr) {
    log("PASSED: ", tr);
  }

  private static void log(String prefix, ITestResult tr) {
    System.out.println(prefix + tr.getName() + "(" + Arrays.asList(tr.getParameters()) + ")");
  }
}
```

In your `pom.xml`:

```
[...]
<plugins>
    [...]
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <properties>
            <property>
              <name>listener</name>
              <value>MyTestListener</value>
            </property>
          </properties>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    [...]
</plugins>
[...]
```

Comment: @Ordiel if this works out for you, be sure to post more complete solution than a reference - for the future generations

Comment: @BorisStrandjev I've just added a sample